# Can I set frame for UIView when use Adaptive Layout

Tags: iphone, ios8

I trying to use `setFrame` for my UIView, but I also use auto layout on it. The trouble is I can setFrame for UIView, in spite of use `setFrame(x, y, w, h)` for it. I realise because of Adaptive Layout deny it, so can I setFrame for it first at runtime before Adaptive Layout adapt? Thank you

Comment: FYI, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use Adaptive Layout together with Auto Layout you should not think in terms of frames.

However, for edge cases, the Auto Layout engine allows you to do "fine tuning" after it has calculated the position of all the elements. Something you could do in your `UIView`code is to set your layout constraints

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
   [self applyMyViewConstraints];
   [super updateConstraints];
}
```

After the system updates all the constraints, it will call `layoutSubviews` in your UIView. At this stage all the frames from the related items are set and final. You can overwrite the Auto Layout frames that you desire.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 200);
}
```